# Jenkins job runs continuously on loop

Tags: jenkins

I've set up a jenkins job to deploy my code at regular intervals of time. However, as soon as I run the build, the job keeps getting queued again and again and keeps running in loop.

I saw a couple of suggestions on previously answered questions that mentioned that restarting the instance might help resolve this issue, but nothing seems to work.

Comment: How are the triggers set up for the job?

Comment: Hi Dibakar, I had scheduled a periodic build with the following schedule
```H 5,18 * * *```
but when I changed it to ```0 5,18 * * *``` the issue seems to have been resolved and it's working fine for now. Any idea what could be causing this?